# Issue with COnfiguration Properties annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-properties

I have a Git configuration and spring server points to that configuration.  Then I created a client with the below configuration.. and expected properties to be populated in the Properties object. Some reason its not working with Spring cloud configuration..But it does work with application.yml or application.properties. I can see bar populated properly.. but not the properties.

any idea?

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@RestController
@RefreshScope
@ComponentScan
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="datasource.mysql.jpa")

public class ConfigClientApplication {

    private Properties properties;

    public Properties getProperties() {
        return properties;
    }

    @Value("${datasource.mysql.jpa.hibernate.dialect:sss}")
    private String bar;
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        String a ="";
        try {
            a = (String)properties.get("datasource.mysql.jpa.hibernate.dialect");
        }catch (Exception e){
            a = e.getMessage();
        }
        return "Hello "+bar + a;
    }
```

Comment: The way you have it set up, the properties that would go into your `properties` var need to be prefixed with `datasource.mysql.jpa.properties.*`.

Comment: I didnt get it..You Mean to say @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="datasource.mysql.jpa") to change to @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="datasource.mysql.jpa.properties.*") ??

Comment: That's what I said. As you have it coded above, that's the only way it will work. The `.properties` is needed because the variable in the class is named `properties`.

Answer (score 1):

Do not combine `@Value` annotation with `@ConfigurationProperties` this way. I had luck to map properties groups to inner classes like this:

```
test1.property1=...
test1.test2.property2=...
test1.test2.property3=...
```

Will be mapped with:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Getter
@Setter
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties(locations = "classpath:myapp.properties")
public class ApplicationProperties {

    private String property1;
    private Test2 test2;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "test2")
    public static class Test2 {
        @NotNull
        private String property2;
        @NotNull
        private String property3;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I Just mapped Value to Verify , is it the issue with Properties or Values to.. I agreed. My actual code does not value annotation. But still this does not work.. With properties.. It worked like anything not with the property object.. which is why i am confused. By the way.. It work fine when I load the properties.. But does not work when i hook it up with cloud config server.